# Is CiviCRM right for our organization?

Tags: civihr

We are a non-profit mission sending agency. We are not looking for donor management software, but we are looking for more of an HR platform where we can manage all of our employees and all of their information so that it is available in multiple ways to multiple people within the organization.

Also does an API exist within the software?

Answer (score 4):

Check this out!

https://civihr.org/

It's an extension (add-on) to core

Answer (score 2):

And there is an API with the software, check https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Using+the+API

Answer (score -1):

I also just wanted to point out we have no updated the information on the link that Karin provided in a while.

You might want to have a look at our 
website: https://civihr.org/
twitter:twitter.com/civi_hr
and wiki: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/HR/CiviHR

Comment: I updated that link!